# Error After updating firebase cloud-messaging dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm updating firebase dependency to the latest version and facing this issue. try to solve this issue but didn't solve this.

old dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

New dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2'
```

Logcat response:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseApp should have a non-empty projectId.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:56)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:86)
        at uffizio.trakzee.main.SettingsActivity.deleteFcmToken(SettingsActivity.kt:1220)
        at uffizio.trakzee.main.SettingsActivity.access$deleteFcmToken(SettingsActivity.kt:76)
        at uffizio.trakzee.main.SettingsActivity$deleteFcmKey$1.call(SettingsActivity.kt:1229)
        at uffizio.trakzee.main.SettingsActivity$deleteFcmKey$1.call(SettingsActivity.kt:76)
```

Comment: If this is the only change you made in your project, you should file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Ya... I've submitted bugs but I want a solution as soon as possible if any face this kind of issue and solved it. that's why I post this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one worked for me.

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        }
    }
```